# How to differentiate iPhone and iPad in universal application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to differentiate the controller for iPhone and iPad.

```
        #ifdef __IPHONE_NA
            {

            UINavigationBar *ipadNavBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 768.0f, 50.0f)];
            [[self view] addSubview: ipadNavBar];

            UINavigationItem *ipadNavItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"EMPLOYEE"];
            [ipadNavBar pushNavigationItem:ipadNavItem animated:NO];
            }
    else 
        {

        UINavigationBar *ipadNavBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 360.0f, 45.0f)];
        [[self view] addSubview: ipadNavBar];



UINavigationItem *ipadNavItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"EMPLOYEE"];
    [ipadNavBar pushNavigationItem:ipadNavItem animated:NO];
    }
```

if saying error unterminated #ifdef

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make use of the constants already present:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    // Some code for iPhone
}
else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    // Some code for iPad
}
```

Naturally you wouldn't need the `else if` statement, you could just use `else` however I'm just using it illustrate the difference constants available.

You can find out more [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) (look at the section on `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM`).

Comment: App needs to be universal for iPad block to get executed.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        NSLog(@"iPad Idiom"); 
    else
        NSLog(@"iPhone Idiom");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone) {

     Console.WriteLine("Phone");

} else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad) {

     Console.WriteLine("Pad");

}
```

Comment: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it will help countless others.